# Removing an object from an array without knowing the index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove an element from an array used the splice method, but I don't know the index of the object that I wish to remove. I've tried adding an ID that mimicks the index to remove the item but this doesn't appear to be working.

```
RandomiseNextQuestion: function(player1qs) {

    // Pick a random question
    this.Questions = player1qs;
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * player1qs.length);
    function findQ(q) { 
        return q.qId === rand;
    }

    this.CurrentQuestion = player1qs.find(findQ);

    if(this.CurrentQuestion) {
        // Process question
    }

    // Remove that question so it can't be used again
    this.Questions.splice(this.CurrentQuestion.qId, 1);
}
```

I've also tried using the 'rand' value to remove the item but that doesn't work either.

Comment: why not just use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and access the element with said index?

Comment: array.indexOf(object) will return the index (or -1 if the object is not in the array)

Comment: If I dot wieither of those wont the random value have reset itself?

Comment: You can pre-shuffle the questions and then use them in order. The effect will be the same as picking a random one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map to find the index of your element

```
var yourArray = ['bla','bloe','blie'];

var elementPos = yourArray.indexOf('bloe');
console.log(elementPos); // this will show the index of the element you want

yourArray.splice(elementPos,1); // this wil remove the element 

console.log(yourArray);
```

you can do it like this I suppose

```
getRandomQuestion: function(playerQuestions) {
    // Pick a random question and return question and index of question
    this.questions = playerQuestions;
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * playerQuestions.length);
    return this.questions[rand];
}

removeQuestion: function(question, playerQuestions){
       playerQuestions.splice(playerQuestions.indexOf(question), 1);
       return playerQuestions; // removes question and gives back the remaining questions
}

processQuestion: function(question){
//do something with the question
}

// you would call it like this
var questionsPlayer1 = ["the meaning of life", "the answer to everything"]
var question = getRandomQuestion(questionsPlayer1);
processQuestion(question);
removeQuestion(question, questionsPlayer1);
```

Comment: How would I find the same element though I found earlier - I dont want to show one element and remove another

Answer (score 1):

All you can do with a single command is a `filter`

```
arr.filter((value) => value !== removeValue)
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep using your array (aka mutable), you will have to use something like:

```
const i = arr.indexOf('value')
arr.splice(i, 1)
```

Comment: It's getting the right index that I'm struggling with becuase it needs to be the index of the item selected here: this.CurrentQuestion = player1qs.find(findQ);

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf uhm, not quite sure what you mean. But you can use `filter` to get an **element** removed from your `this.Questions` array. Something like `this.Questions = this.Questions.filter((element) => element !== usedElement)`. Element will never fail because it is not dependent on the index.